# EEVEE Sub Division Surfaces with Blocky Shading

Tags: rendering, shaders, eevee-render-engine

I'm having an issue rendering subdivision surfaces in EEVEE and can not find an answer anywhere.

When applying subdivision surfaces to objects in EEVEE, it creates very distorted reflections in the shading. Everything renders perfect in Cycles but this is the result I get in EEVEE.

With subdivision surface modifier, you can see the blocky shading.

[image]

Here without subdivision surface, everything is smooth.

[image]

[image]
Here is the topology with subD applied so you can see the modifier is applying clean topology as well. 
[image]

Also here is a render I created of the model in cycles, you can see the issue doesn't occur in Cycles renders.

[image]

I have no idea what is causing this, I appreciate any help.

Comment: It's likely related to your topology. Can you add a screenshot of the wireframe?

Comment: I uploaded the wireframe image

Comment: Also uploaded my cycles render to see the shading issue is not present

Comment: Have you experimented with the *Screen Space Reflection* settings, like the trace precision? Increasing it may help.

Comment: Yeah, I tried all the settings there in that panel, also with creating the reflection cube map and baking the lighting. I thought it was a issue in Screen Space Reflection to begin with. Then I removed that setting completely and applied just a base principled shader and only the basic scene settings and the shading still has that issue. Also should note even applying the subD modifier it still does it as well.

Comment: Do you have your bevel modifier after your subsurf modifier? It may be beveling your internal edges...

Comment: 1) A file would be nice. Considering the dates, I imagine you no longer have one though....  2)  Always look for custom normals in object data/geometry.  3) Always consider the impact of a normal map, bump map, or displacement in your shader nodes.

Answer (score 0):

The object's scale is too large or too small for Eevee to properly apply the shader. Apply the scale so that everything is in order.
I just had the same problem and it solved the problem for me.